# Echo a un input valores de una sesión

Tags: php, html

Estoy intentando algo así

```
<input value="<?php echo $_SESSION[empleados][nombre]?>">
```

**La sesión proviene de una consulta introducida en una array**

Es decir:

```
<?php
while ($f=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$nombre=$f['nombre'];
$sueldo=$f['sueldo'];

} $datosnuevos=array('id'=>$_GET['id'],'Nombre'=>$nombre,'Sueldo'=>$sueldo);
array_push($arreglo,$datosnuevos);
$_SESSION['empleados']=$arreglo;
?>
```

por cada uno de los elementos en la sesión imprimir su nombre separados por comas entre uno y otro dentro de un mismo input.

Es decir:

```
<input value="pepito, juanito, Luis">
```

Creo que la forma de hacer esto es incluyéndolos en un array pero alguien puede indicarme como??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la funcion `implode()` tan simple como;

```
$nombres = implode(',',$_SESSION['empleados']);
echo '<input value="' . $nombres . '">
```

La función `implode()` devuelve un string que contiene los valores del array.

**$string (opcional):** Cadena de texto con la que podemos dividir cada elemento del array dentro del string resultante.

**$array (obligatorio):** Array que queremos convertir en cadena.

Edito mi respuesta para agregar mas contenido;

Pueden utilizar la siguiente función para hacer un `multi implode`;

```
function multi_implode($array, $glue) {
    $ret = '';

    foreach ($array as $item) {
        if (is_array($item)) {
            $ret .= multi_implode($item, $glue) . $glue;
        } else {
            $ret .= $item . $glue;
        }
    }

    $ret = substr($ret, 0, 0-strlen($glue));

    return $ret;
}
echo multi_implode($_SESSION['empleados'],',');
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899971/implode-and-explode-multi-dimensional-arrays

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro gracias, he corregido mi respuesta

Comment: ok ahora tengo el problema de que imprime array,array como soluciono esto? puedo hacer algo así como un doble implode?

Comment: @ger Si me proporcionas mas de tu código puedo ayudarte, tengo la limitación de que no se de donde provienen tus ni cuantas dimensiones tiene tu arreglo.

Comment: ya modifique mi código ahora podría ayudarme

Comment: @ger he agregado mas información y una función extra.

Answer (score -1):

Creo que lo que intentas obtener es algo así:

```
<input value="pepito">
<input value="jaimito">
<input value="juanito">
```

a partir de un array multidimensional (ok, en sesión), que los guarda. Entonces, lo que tienes en sesión, dentro de 'empleado', es algo como esto:

```
[
    [
        'nombre' => 'Pepito',
        'salario' => 900,
    ],
    [
        'nombre' => 'Jaimito',
        'salario' => 950,
    ],
    [
        'nombre' => 'Juanito',
        'salario' => 1900,
    ],
];
```

entonces, para obtener todos los empleados:

```
$arr_empleados = $_SESSION[ 'empleado' ];
```

Y para imprimir los inputs puedes hacer:

```
foreach($arr_empleados as $empleado) {

    echo '<input value="' . $empleado[ 'nombre' ] . '">';
}
```

**Editado: respondo a las aclaraciones en la pregunta**

Para obtener algo así:

```
<input value="pepito, juanito, Luis">
```

sólo varía un poco el proceso de impresión de valores, es decir, una vez tienes el array con los empleados: `$arr_empleados`, haces lo siguiente:

```
//Cuenta elementos para no poner coma al final
$num = count($arr_empleados) - 1;

echo '<input value="'; //abre input y atributo value
foreach($arr_empleados as $key => $empleado) {

    echo $empleado['nombre'];

    if ($key < $num)
        echo ', ';
}
echo '">'; //cierra input y atributo value
```

Comment: ok lo siento formule mal la pregunta ya edite la pregunta para clarificar que es lo que quiero